# Stop Azure AD from logging user in automatically

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

So I have to ask here, because I am not sure where I am going wrong with this one.

We are developing an asp.net core application with Azure Enterprise AD, and we have an azure  application configured as proxy (I think that's correct), also an azure service principal which sets what users are allowed to log in.

We are also using services.OpenIdConnect which is setup with signin-scheme and this all works.
When the user tried goes to login at /account/login, a Challenge is sent to azure and the two-factor process starts. After the process is completed we get a callback to /account/loggedin, and the user is successfully logged in. This matches the intended setup.

The issue starts when the user wants to log off the application (not single-signout)
According to the information I could find we just need to remove all traces locally, so we call HttpContext.SignOutAsync(), as well as deleting the cookie.

By now there are no traces left locally of the user being logged in.

If a new user now wants to log in and goes to /account/login, another Challenge is sent to Azure, but this time the challenge returns immediately with the old information from the first user, so the first user is immediately logged in without the login dialo, even if the first time he logged in he chose 'No' in the 'Stay signed in' dialog.

This makes it very hard for multiple users to use the same machine. Because the first user will be logged in again every time, even if a second person is now trying to login.

I am sure this is working as expected for someone, but it really isnt working for me, and I need to figure out who I should talk to. Is it the guy who setup the enterprise directory and directory application in portal.azure.com, or am I going about this the wrong way? It was really hard to find information about logging out from Azure AD unless you want to do single-signout.

Most feedback is appreciated :P

The authentication code is here: https://codefile.io/f/58h0eZdvBv

Keep in mind this is an Optimizely solution with two authentication methods, azure ad for employees and asp.net identity for ordinary users.

Comment: Post the relevant Authentication setup from program.cs.

Comment: I added some code now. From our startup.cs I just call .AddMixedModeLogin()

Answer (score 0):

When you sign in to Azure, not only you get a cookie. Also, the Azure AD server keeps a session for you. 
The right way to signout should be calling the Azure signout endpoint https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc#send-a-sign-out-request which clear both the server session and browser cookie.
If you just clear the cookie at client side. Only your client act like you have sign out. But when you communicate the Azure AD server ,some unexpected behaviour may happen.